# Tensoring two short exact sequences

Tags: algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and consider the following short exact sequences of $R$-modules
\begin{align}
&0 \to M' \to M \stackrel{f}{\to} M'' {\to} 0 \qquad \text{and } \\
&0 \to N' \to N \stackrel{g}{\to} N'' \to 0.
\end{align}

By the right exactness of the tensor product, one can see that 
$$
M \otimes_R N \stackrel{f \otimes g}{\to} M'' \otimes_R N'' \to 0
$$ 
is exact.

What is the kernel of this? Of course, $M' \otimes N, N' \otimes M$ are in the kernel.

> Question: How explicitly can we describe the kernel of $f \otimes g$?

Comment: Tensoring the short exact sequences you get a big 2D  diagram with columns and rows coming from long exact sequences for Tor. Frommthat you can read a description of the kernel.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Would you mind writing some component on the 2D diagram? Or a reference should be fine.